Smooth closing of circular arcs
I try to draw a closed shape by using circular arcs with following code:

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=1.0,black,thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
    \node[] at (0,0) {(0, 0)};

    \def\Rone{4} % Radius of the arc from center A
    \def\Rtwo{2} % Radius of the arc from center B
    \def\Rthree{8} % Radius of the arc from center C
    
    % Define begining points
    \coordinate (A) at (4,2);   
    \coordinate (B) at (4,2);   
    \coordinate (C) at (2,4);   

    % Draw arcs
    % Left arc from center A
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (A) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=-215, radius=\Rone] coordinate (P1);

    % Top arc from center B
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (B) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=-180, radius=\Rtwo] coordinate (P2);

    % Bottom arc from center C
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (C) arc[start angle=0, end angle=32.80, radius=\Rthree] coordinate (P3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The result here looks ok at first glance, except that two arcs -- drawn from center A and from center C -- are not smoothly joined at their top ends. How can I connect those ends ?

To use line join and fill, everything needs to be in the same \draw. It is not enough that the arcs end near each other - they need to use the same point. To make the third closing arc, you could use arc to from ext.paths.arcto like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.arcto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[cyan, line width=4pt, fill=blue!20] (2,4) 
arc[start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=2] 
arc[start angle=-90, end angle=-215, radius=4] 
arc to[radius=8, clockwise] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


